# empty .vimrc causing some scripts to not load?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Without having **~/.vimrc**, I get the following list when I run`:scriptnames` in vim

```
  1: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0134/share/vim/vim80/defaults.vim
  2: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0134/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syntax.vim
  3: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0134/share/vim/vim80/syntax/synload.vim
  4: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0134/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syncolor.vim
  5: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0134/share/vim/vim80/filetype.vim
  6: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0134/share/vim/vim80/ftplugin.vim
  7: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0134/share/vim/vim80/indent.vim
  8: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0134/share/vim/vim80/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
  9: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0134/share/vim/vim80/plugin/gzip.vim
 10: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0134/share/vim/vim80/plugin/logiPat.vim
 11: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0134/share/vim/vim80/plugin/manpager.vim
 12: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0134/share/vim/vim80/plugin/matchparen.vim
 13: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0134/share/vim/vim80/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
 14: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0134/share/vim/vim80/plugin/rrhelper.vim
 15: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0134/share/vim/vim80/plugin/spellfile.vim
 16: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0134/share/vim/vim80/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 17: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0134/share/vim/vim80/plugin/tohtml.vim
 18: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0134/share/vim/vim80/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 19: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0134/share/vim/vim80/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
```

However, if I simply do **touch ~/.vimrc** my `:scriptnames` becomes this

```
  1: ~/.vimrc
  2: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0134/share/vim/vim80/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
  3: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0134/share/vim/vim80/plugin/gzip.vim
  4: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0134/share/vim/vim80/plugin/logiPat.vim
  5: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0134/share/vim/vim80/plugin/manpager.vim
  6: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0134/share/vim/vim80/plugin/matchparen.vim
  7: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0134/share/vim/vim80/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
  8: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0134/share/vim/vim80/plugin/rrhelper.vim
  9: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0134/share/vim/vim80/plugin/spellfile.vim
 10: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0134/share/vim/vim80/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 11: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0134/share/vim/vim80/plugin/tohtml.vim
 12: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0134/share/vim/vim80/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 13: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0134/share/vim/vim80/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
```

What's causing vim to skip the default plugins?
I really like the defaults, Any way I can keep change settings in vimrc file without overriding defaults?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a vimrc Vim will load `/usr/share/vim/vim80/defaults.vim`. You can see that the first line:

```
1: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0134/share/vim/vim80/defaults.vim
```

Is missing from your second `:scriptnames` output.

From [`:help defaults.vim`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#defaults%2evim):

```
If Vim is started normally and no user vimrc file is found, the
$VIMRUTIME/defaults.vim script is loaded.

[...]

This should work well for new Vim users.  If you create your own .vimrc, it is
recommended to add this line somewhere near the top:
        unlet! skip_defaults_vim
        source $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim
```

Note that this applies *only* to Vim 8. Vim 7.4 and earlier didn't ship with the `defaults.vim` file.

Comment: Thanks! That makes a lot of sense. I recently upgraded to Vim 8 and starting noticing this. 
My solution was to copying part of `defaults.vim` and placed it in my *~/.vimrc*